# keeping track of valid rows in csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file like this:

```
    1 2 3 4 5 6
    4 5 6 3 # 2
    2 4 5 6 3 1 
    3 4 % $ 2 1
    1 2 3 4 5 8
```

I only want the rows that have all numbers, and not any other characters. Is there a way to keep track of only the correct rows, which only have numbers in them.

So far I only have this:

```
import csv
def get_rows(csv_file):

    csv_read = open(csv_file)
    reader = csv.reader(csv_read)

    invalid_rows = 0
    for row in reader:
```

I'm just not sure how to keep track of the correct rows, and be able to add the invalid rows to a counter. I want to be able to use the correct rows in the future, and simply add the number of incorrect rows to a counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure python solution:

```
$ cat data 
1 2 3 4 5 6
4 5 6 3 # 2
2 4 5 6 3 1 
3 4 % $ 2 1
1 2 3 4 5 8
$ cat p.py 
import csv, re

validRows=[]
with open('data', 'r') as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        if all([re.match(r'^\d+$', item) is not None for item in row]):
            validRows+=[row]
print(validRows)
$ python3 p.py 
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '8']]
$
```

Without using `re`:

```
import csv

validRows=[]
with open('data', 'r') as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        if all([item.isdigit() for item in row]):
            validRows+=[row]
print(validRows)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using pandas, which is very powerful when working with tabular data.
See article here for the used methods: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html

Note: this code is types from memory, so may not work

```
import pandas as pd

data_frame = pandas.read_csv(csv_file)
data_frame.transpose() # we are interested in the rows, but pandas is primarily column oriented
incorrect_cols = data_frame.select_dtypes(exclude=["number"])
number_cols = data_frame.select_dtypes(include=["number"])
number_cols.transpose() # now the old format again
```